# How to convert a delphi form's width and height pixels into dialog units?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm trying to calculate a Delphi form's width and height pixels into accurate dialog units to create a .rc (resource script) file that uses a DIALOGEX statement. So far, I have not been able to calculate the correct dialog units using Microsoft's formula described here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/145994/how-to-calculate-dialog-box-units-based-on-the-current-font-in-visual

The above link uses the `GetDialogBaseUnits` Win32 API call but this does not work since that API function uses the system font. So this is useless. Even Microsoft says that we should use `MapDialogRect` instead. So, using the formula provided here on how to calculate dialog base units with non-system-based fonts https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/125681/how-to-calculate-dialog-base-units-with-non-system-based-font

> 1 horz dialog base unit == (2 * average char width  dialog font / 
>                                   average char width  system font) pixels
>
> 1 vert dialog base unit == (2 * average char height dialog font  / 
>                                    average char height system font) pixels

I have tried something like this:

```
  xPixels := 200
  yPixels := 50;

  dc := GetDC(0);

  SelectObject(dc,handle);  // handle := f.Font.Handle  (f := TForm created)
  if not GetTextMetrics(dc, tm) then
    ShowMessage('Error');
  avgHeight := tm.tmHeight / 8.0;

  GetTextExtentPoint32(dc,
       PChar('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 52,
       size);
  avgWidth := size.cx / 52.0;

  avgSysWidth := 5;   // Made up value, how to calculate?
  avgSysHeight := 1;  // Made up value, how to calculate?

  horzPixels := Round(2 * 1 * (avgWidth / avgSysWidth));
  vertPixels := Round(2 * 1 * (avgHeight / avgSysHeight));

  HorizontalDialogBaseUnit := Round(xPixels / horzPixels);
  VerticalDialogBaseUnit := Round(yPixels / vertPixels);
```

Note that `handle` is from the created forms Font handle. The `avgSysWidth` and `avgSysHeight` I'm not sure how to get to those values.

I've been looking at this for two days and can't seem to see the simplest way to get to the dialog units. Am I completely off?

**Update 2:**
My updated function:

```
// xPixesl := 400
// yPixels := 200
procedure Tdm.GetDlgBaseUnits(handle: HWND; xPixels, yPixels: integer; out HorizontalDLUs, VerticalDLUs: integer);
var
  dc: HDC;
  tm: TTextMetric;
  size: TSize;
  avgWidth, avgHeight: real;
  VerticalDlu, HorizontalDlu: real;
//  DialogUnits: Cardinal;
begin
//  DialogUnits := GetDialogBaseUnits;
  dc := GetDC(0);

  SelectObject(dc,handle);
  GetTextMetrics(dc, tm);
  avgHeight := tm.tmHeight;

  GetTextExtentPoint32(dc,
       PChar('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 52,
       size);
  avgWidth := size.cx / 52.0;

  HorizontalDLUs := Round( (4 * xPixels) / avgWidth );
  VerticalDLUs := Round( (8 * yPixels) / avgHeight );

//  HorizontalDLUs := Round( (xPixels / (avgWidth * LOWORD(DialogUnits))));
//  VerticalDLUs := Round( (yPixels / (avgHeight * HIWORD(DialogUnits))));
end;
```

Given a 400z200 pixel form, the above function produces 269 by 123 DLUs. Here is a picture of the form. The left one is the designed form in 400x200 pixels and the right one is produced and created form based on:

```
DesignForm DIALOGEX 0, 0, 269, 123
STYLE  WS_CAPTION | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP
CAPTION "DesignForm"
CLASS "DLGCLASS"
FONT 8, "Tahoma"
{
}
```

[image]

Comment: The picture looks right, if you consider that the dialog resource specifies the _client_ dimensions, and the Delphi form gives you _window_ coordinates.

Comment: Ahhh, I completely missed this simple fact. Thank you Rob. I can't believe I overlooked this small detail. Amazing. I used ClientWidth  and ClientHeight of the form and it now is a perfect conversion. You guys Rock!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GetTextMetrics(dc, tm);
avgHeight := tm.tmHeight;

GetTextExtentPoint32(dc,
   PChar('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 52,
   size);
avgWidth := Round( size.cx / 52.0 );

HorizontalDLUs := Round( (4 * xPixels) / avgWidth );
VerticalDLUs := Round( (8 * yPixels) / avgHeight );
```

A DLU is based on the size of the dialog box font. A horizontal DLU is the average width of the dialog box font divided by four. A vertical DLU is the height of the font divided by eight.

Also see remarks section in [GetDialogBaseUnits function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms645475(v=vs.85).aspx) with recomendation to use MulDiv function.

Comment: I had to remove the Rounds for the horizontal and vertical numbers because it was producing incorrect results. Still, I had to multiply the vertical dialog base units by 10. I've updated my question to see updated example of the function.

Comment: You have wrong formula calculating avgHeight. Don't divide by 8, tm.tmHeight is a font height.
If you are using integers, you should use bigger units then DLU, because of high rounding errors. Use base dialog unit witch is equal 4 x 8 dlu. Base dialog unit is equal averange size of font. Edited my answer

Comment: @Dainiel, using your updated formula, the created dialog is still visible a bit larger than the original form. My sample form of 800 pixels by 400 pixels produces 539 DLU by 246 DLU. Visibly, I would guess the form is about 40-50 pixels larger in width and height. Still something seems off.

Comment: width and height in dialog template specifies client size (without frame).

Comment: Ahhh, I completely missed this simple fact. Thank you Daniel and Rob. I can't believe I overlooked this small detail. Amazing. I used ClientWidth  and ClientHeight of the form and it now is a perfect conversion.

Comment: I think you still will be few DLU off. I was wrong with rounding. Found my old source (in C++) and avgWidth is rounded to integer "int avg_width = (int)( ( size.cx + 26 ) / 52 );" so avgWidth should be rounded to full integer.

Answer (score 2):

[`GetDialogBaseUnits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645475.aspx) isn't actually so "useless." It will tell you the average height and width of the system font in pixels:

```
avgSysWidth := LoWord(GetDialogBaseUnits);
avgSysHeight := HiWord(GetDialogBaseUnits);
```

Comment: Thank you Rob. I did use the GetDialogBasedUnits before but it had no affect on calculations of the DLUs.